# Using signals in django, trying to generate code for SMS verification but generated code is not visible in admin. what am i missing?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-apps

folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SyYE.png)

models.py from face_detect

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    add = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

models.py from otp

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from face_detect.models import Profile
import random
# Create your models here.

class Code(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

    #otp verification
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        number_list = [x for x in range(10)]
        code_items = []

        for i in range(5):
            num = random.choice(number_list)
            code_items.append(num)

        code_string = "".join(str(item) for item in code_items)
        self.mobile = code_string

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

signals.py from otp

```
from face_detect.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Code
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def post_save_generate_code(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Code.objects.create(user=instance)
```

apps.py from otp

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class OtpConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'otp'

    def ready(self):
        import otp.signals
```

**init**.py from otp

```
default_app_config = 'otp.apps.OtpConfig'
```

admin.py from otp

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Code
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Code)
```

code seen in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/otp/code/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHEjt.png)

code is not visible.

how can i make the code visible so i can use it for otp verification while login.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the value of `number`of your code instance?

Comment: got it self.number = code_string in models.py from otp

Comment: yeah also you dont need to cast it to str here your number is already char field`str(self.number)`

Comment: Have you checked the database? Is the code available there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin page you will see the `__str__` method, so there seems to be nothing wrong with your code most probably your code instance's value is "", Also one other thing

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.number)
```

you dont need to cast it to str here its already char field
and another thing is here:

```
   def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

in `Profile` model you made user nullable so this means not all the profile instances might not have user so you will get `NoneType has no attribute username`
change it to this to prevent this errors:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username if self.user else ""
```